# how to generate pdf through fpdf via php

Tags: php, dynamic, fpdf

I have question. I have inserted form in my html webpage. I want to generate pdf after filling data in that form and option for to save as PDFs. Any idea.
Another thing I refer FPDF source.But I cannot understand.

The php code to be saved as Php? In my website,then what to run,php? or to make another html to run?

Give me full details like which file ,to give which name & where to save?

From:trek

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read: http://whathaveyoutried.com - and actually try to code before asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your can try [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) you can find good example here.

Comment: yup TCPDF is the standard for php-html to pdf.

Comment: Yes you can convert from php-html to pdf very easily with the examples listed in the official site